# Android Studio Image Asset

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm encountering an issue with image assets in Android Studio's Asset Studio. Whenever I attempt to utilize clip art, the normal icons are not displayed; instead, I see the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mFLa.png)
How can I resolve this problem and ensure that the correct icons are shown?

Comment: can't understand your question, what are you trying to do and what are your results,

Comment: on clip art there is like normal icons that we know for example : settings icons..
but for me i don't have them

Comment: @Moe Do you want to navigate to Vector Icons template page as you show in the picture? Currently its not working for you? Or Do you want to navigate to Custom Vector Icon page where you can select your own Vector image?

Comment: in the Picture i showed the icons are not right if you look up the default  clip art icons  they are diffrent from what i have

Comment: search for it!!!